# why is addListenerForSingleValueEvent returning null outside of onDataChange scope?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im tryng to retrieve data from firebase data base with this code:

```
private void getUserInfo() {

        databaseReference.child("users").child("userId").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Usuario user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

userId being the knot with the value that i want...inside the scope of onDataChange() i do get the data that i want, the problem is that i cant assign the result to any global variabeles,as it always results null outside the scope.Example:

```
 private void getUserInfo() {

        databaseReference.child("users").child(Base64Custom.codificarBase64(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail())).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Usuario user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                globalUser = user;


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
```

global user is a global variable, but outside onDataChange, it is always null.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseReference.child("users").child(Base64Custom.codificarBase64(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail())).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
Usuario user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
globalUser = user;

//INSIDE THE SCOPE OF ON DATA CHANGE
//----------------------------------
//YOU MUST USE THE USER OBJECT HERE

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});


//OUTSIDE THE SCOPE OF ON DATA CHANGE
--------------------------------------
//YOU CANT USE THE USER  OBJECT HERE, BECAUSE THERE IS NO GUARANTEE THAT THE 

//ON DATA CHANGE() METHOD WILL RUN BEFORE THIS AREA HERE, SO YOUR OBJECT 

//MIGHT REMAIN NULL HERE.
```